# An identity satisfied by 'harmonic numbers'

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fractions, harmonic-numbers

Given the $harmonic\;numbers$ $$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac 1 k ,n\!>\!0,H_0=0$$ prove $$\sum_{k=0}^n H_k=(n+1)H_n-n$$ Also in the terminology according to the book A=B would you not agree that the $H_k$ cannot be identified as the terms in a hypergeometric series ? That is at least not a single  hypergeometric series.

Comment: According to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2456007/42969, that identity “simply follows from summation by parts.” –  I do not understand the second part of the question.

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/464957/42969.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify the second part: What is “the terminology according to the book A=B”? Why do you think that the $H_k$ are not terms of a hypergeometric series?

Comment: As far as the the terminology i must say it is not all that clear to me either but i think mainly it takes the ratio of the n+1 term to the n'th term and requires it to be a rational function of the summation index. I get that as the index approaches infinity it seems to me to be an infinite number of terms in the ratio expression ? Why do think the $H_k$ are terms of a hypergeometric series and what exactly is that series in terms of the somewhat standard $pFq[...]$ notation of the numerator and denominator entries.