# Wrong seats in a cinema

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A friend of mine (an I.T. guy) gave me this tricky probability problem, that I couldn't solve.

$n$ persons go to a cinema that has $n$ seats, and everyone of them has an assigned position written on the ticket.

The first person $p_1$ commits an error and chooses the wrong seat.

Then $p_2,\ldots,p_n$ arrive (in order) and they choose their seat according to the following rule:

*"If the assigned seat is free, go there. Otherwise, choose a random seat among the free ones."*

What is the probability for the last person $p_n$ to sit in his assigned seat?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane

Comment: thank you! this is slightly different, in the sense that the choice of $p_1$ is fixed, but should be easy now to adapt the answer...