# Probability last person sits in correct seat

Tags: probability, puzzle

There are 26 people lettered A to Z each has randomly been allocated a random unique integer from 1 to 26. There are 26 seats numbered 1 to 26.

The people enter in alphabetical order and sit on their corresponding seat if possible.

The first 4 people forgot their numbers and just sat in a random seat. All the people after the initial 4 remember their number but if their seat is taken they randomly sit in a seat available.

What is the probability that Z sits in his allocated seat?

---

Obviously Z sits in correct seat if A to D randomly sat in the 4 seats allocated to them which is; $$\frac{2}{13}\times\frac{3}{25}\times\frac{1}{12}\times\frac{1}{23}=\frac{1}{14950}$$

My issue from here is how do I calculate the probability that Z sits in correct seat if one of the initial 4 people doesn't sit in their allocated seats?

Comment: Note:  the variant wherein only the first person has forgotten their seat is discussed in many places, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane).  This differs from that in that more than one person has forgotten their seat.

Comment: Hint:  the logic here is pretty much the same as in the standard variant.  We only care about the selection of seats $A,B,C,D,Z$.  Most of the people just go to their assigned seats and are therefore irrelevant. If someone chooses a non-$Z$ letter below them in the alphabet then the important decision is merely deferred.   Each "live" choice is a choice between $A,B,C,D,Z$ and, as these are effectively indistinguishable, the answer is $\frac 15$.