# Expected number of wrong seats on plane

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expectation, puzzle

Many people will be familiar with the set up of this problem: you have an aeroplane with 100 seats, and 100 passengers who have been allocated unique seats. The first passenger forgets their ticket, and so takes a random seat. The remaining passengers enter the plane. If their seat is empty, they take it. If it is occupied, they take a random seat on the plane.

At this point, the question that is usually asked it "what is the probability that the 100th person gets their allocated seat". This was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane).

My question is a bit different. By the time all the passengers have boarded what is the expected number of passengers in the wrong seat? I have seen many people ask this as a follow up question to the first on some other online forums, but there doesn't appear to be a convincing answer anywhere.

**Attempt:**

Looking at smaller sized planes, we can come up with a conjecture than for a plane of size $n$, we have $$\text{expectation}=\begin{cases}1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}&n\text{ is even}\\\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n&n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

When trying to compute the expectation for even $n$ as a sum, we get a very complicated expression, of the form $$\frac1n\left(2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i+3\sum_{i\ne j,i,j=1}^{n-1}\frac1{ij}+4\sum_{i\ne j\ne k,i,j,k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{ijk}\cdots\right)$$

How can we derive the result I have conjectured?

---

$\small\text{Edit:}$

$\small\text{The conjecture was wrong in the odd case - the expectation is always equal to }\small\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac1i\small\text{whether }n\small\text{ is even or odd. (As shown by the answers and @Akababa's comment)}$

Comment: But when $n=3$ I got $\frac32$

Comment: @akababa the answers given don't seem to assume anything about it being even, so I suppose you're right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the number of incorrect seats occupied by passenger $k$.  Obviously $X_k$ is either $0$ or $1$; by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/taking-seats-on-a-plane/56115#56115) we have
$$P(X_k=1)=\frac1{n+2-k}\quad\hbox{for $k=2,3,\ldots,n$}\ ;$$
hence
$$E(X_k)=0\cdot P(X_k{=}0)+1\cdot P(X_k{=}1)=\frac1{n+2-k}\ .$$
Similarly,
$$E(X_1)=\frac{n-1}n=1-\frac1n\ .$$
The total number of passengers in the wrong seat is $T_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, and by linearity its expected value is
$$E(X_1)+E(X_2)+E(X_3)+\cdots+E(X_n)
  =\Bigl(1-\frac1n\Bigr)+\frac1n+\frac1{n-1}+\cdots+\frac12\ ,$$
that is,
$$E(T_n)=1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1{n-1}\ ,$$
provided $n>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Each configuration is associated to a cycle like $1\mapsto 5\mapsto 8\mapsto 72\mapsto 1$, meaning that the first person takes the fifth place, the fifth person takes the eighth place, $\ldots$, the $72$th persone takes the first place. If this occurs any other person besides $1,5,8,72$ takes his/her place. The probability that $1\mapsto 5\mapsto 8\mapsto 72\mapsto 1$ occurs is $\frac{1}{101-1}\cdot\frac{1}{101-5}\cdot\frac{1}{101-8}\cdot\frac{1}{101-72}$ and by this way there are four people in the wrong place.

The probability that $0$ people are in the wrong place is $\frac{1}{100}$.
The probability that just $1$ person is in the wrong place is zero.
The probability that $2$ people are in the wrong place (configurations $1\mapsto m\mapsto 1$) is given by $\frac{1}{100}$ times the sum of $\frac{1}{101-k}$ for $k$ that goes from $2$ to $100$, i.e. by the coefficient of $x^2$ in

$$ g(x)=\frac{x}{101-1}\left(1+\frac{x}{101-2}\right)\cdot\left(1+\frac{x}{101-3}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(1+\frac{x}{101-100}\right).$$
Similarly, the probability that $k\geq 2$ people are in the wrong place is given by the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g(x)$. In particular the average value of the number of people in the wrong place is given by
$$ \sum_{k\geq 2} k\cdot [x^k]g(x) = \left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(g(x)-\frac{x}{100}\right)\right|_{x=1}=g'(1)-\frac{1}{100}=\frac{g'(1)}{g(1)}-\frac{1}{100}.$$
On the other hand $\log(g(x))=\log(x)-\log(100)+\log\left(1+\frac{x}{99}\right)+\ldots+\log\left(1+\frac{x}{1}\right)$, hence

$$ \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{99+x}+\frac{1}{98+x}+\ldots+\frac{1}{1+x} $$
and $\frac{g'(1)}{g(1)}$ equals the $100$th harmonic number $H_{100}$.
 It follows that the wanted average value is $H_{99}\approx 5.17738$.

The same argument works for any other number of seats $s\geq 3$ and it does not depend on the parity of the number of seats. By considering $g''(x)$ you may also compute the variance of the random variable $W$ giving the number of people in the wrong place:

$$\operatorname{Var}[W]=\mathbb{E}[W^2]-\mathbb{E}[W]^2 = -H_{s-1}^2+\sum_{n\geq 2}n^2\cdot [x^n]g(x) $$
equals 
$$ -H_{s-1}^2+H_{s-1}+g''(1) = H_{s-1}-H_{s-1}^2+H_s^2+\left.\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}\right)\right|_{x=1}$$
such that
$$\operatorname{Var}[W]=H_{s-1}\left(1+\frac{2}{s}\right)-H_{s-1}^{(2)}. $$
For large values of $s$ the distribution of $W$ is very well approximated by a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Comment: I liked this answer too, since it seemed more intuitive to me to start in a similar way with those sums. The trick with derivatives was very neat, though I did not spot this (or think to define such a $g(x)$). I accepted the other answer though since it was more elementary though. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: +1. Would you care to derive your claim in the last sentence, which I have posed as a question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3256953/64809?