# Asymptotics of the probability of passengers on wrong airplane seats

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, asymptotics, generating-functions

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2876797/64809) Jack D'Aurizio asserts that the probability $W(s,k)$ of $k$ passengers taking wrong seats on a plane capacity of $s$ seats, or the generating function coefficient $[x^k]g(s,x)$, approaches a Poison distribution as $s\to\infty$. Is this true? Is so, how does one derive it rigorously?